# Regex 'or' operator avoid repetition

Tags: c#, .net, regex

How can I use the `or` operator while not allowing repetition? In other words the regex:

```
(word1|word2|word3)+
```

will match    `word1word2` but will also match `word1word1` which I don't want that because the word word1 is being repeated. How can I avoid repetition?

In summary I will like the following subjects to match:

```
word1word2word3
word1
word2
word3word2
```

Note all of them match cause there is no repetition. And I will like the following subjects to fail:

```
word1word2word1
word2word2
word3word1word2word2
```

### Edit

Thanks to [@Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61974/mark-byers)  I know have:

```
(?xi)

(?:  
        (?<A>word1|word2)(?!  .*  \k<A> )      # match for word1 or word2 but make sure that if you capture it it does not follow what it was just captured
    |   (?<B>word3|word4)(?!  .*  \k<B> )
)+
```

because I am interested in seeing if something was captured in group A or B.

Comment: Have you looked at capturing groups?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use [negative lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
^(?:word1(?!.*word1)|word2(?!.*word2)|word3(?!.*word3))+$
```

See it working online: [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/vVzB3H3FmN)

Comment: +1 for interesting solution, not what I would have thought of using capturing groups

Comment: This could be problematic in some cases, eg if word 1 and 2 is `hell` and `hello`.

Comment: I don't like the word "problematic". I prefer to say "challenging". :-)

Answer (score 4):

The lookahead solutions will not work in several cases, you can solve this properly, without lookarounds, by using a construct like this:

```
(?:(?(1)(?!))(word1)|(?(2)(?!))(word2)|(?(3)(?!))(word3))+
```

This works even if some words are substrings of others and will also work if you just want to find the matching substrings of a larger string (and not only match whole string).

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/kIOiwy).

It simply works by failing the alteration if it has been matched previously, done by `(?(1)(?!))`. `(?(1)foo)` is a conditional, and will match `foo` if group `1` has previously matched. `(?!)` always fails.

Answer (score 0):

Byers' solution is too hard coded and gets quite cumbersome after the letters increases.. Why not simply have the regex look for duplicate match?

```
([^\d]+\d)+(?=.*\1)
```

If that matches, that match signifies that a repetition has been found in the pattern. If the match doesn't work you have a valid set of data.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a negative look-ahead containing a back reference:

```
^(?:(word1|word2|word3)(?!.*\1))+$
```

where `\1` refers to the match of the capture group `(word1|word2|word3)`.

Note that this assumes `word2` cannot be formed by appending characters to `word1`, and that `word3` cannot be formed by appending characters to `word1` or `word2`.