# how to combine two regex patterns

Tags: c#, regex

I have one pattern to match Visa cards and one to match Mastercard. How can I combine these two to match both Visa and Mastercard? I just need to know if the card number matches Visa or Mastercard, if not it's not supported.

Visa:

```
^4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?
```

Mastercard:

```
/^5[1-5]\d{14}$/
```

Comment: Check this- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14740661/regex-or-operator-avoid-repetition and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/alternation-constructs-in-regular-expressions

Comment: Both answers below are wrong as they will find a match in `4012345678912123DEWQRRgf54^%&%^*#^#$%@#$%#^%&`. You need `^(?:4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?|5[1-5][0-9]{14})$`. Do not use `\d` in .NET regex if you actually want to match ASCII digits, use `[0-9]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add a | symbol

```
^(4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?)|(5[1-5]\d{14})$
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many resources which over a good and complete overview of what regular expressions in various dialects accept. Almost all of them have the `|`, the vertical bar 'or' operator: https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html

```
^4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?|5[1-5]\d{14}$
```